# How can I force R to include contributors (or other roles) in my package's citation() output?

Tags: r, packaging, r-package

I'm currently writing my first R package, following Hadley Wickham's excellent [book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) on the topic. The section of the book linked above includes examples for adding authors through the package's `DESCRIPTION` file.

Dr. Wickham notes that "The [full list of roles](http://www.loc.gov/marc/relators/relaterm.html) is extremely comprehensive. Should your package have a woodcutter ('wdc'), lyricist ('lyr') or costume designer ('cst'), rest comfortably that you can correctly describe their role in creating your package."

The problem that I'm experiencing is that only people with the 'author' role are included in the output of `citation()` for the package -- woodcutters, lyricists, and costume designers are not. I'd like for non-author contributors to my package to be included in the citation, but don't want to (incorrectly) list them as authors (i.e., as having the role of "author" / `aut`).

For example, if I include the following in my `DESCRIPTION` file (`csp` is [listed as](https://www.loc.gov/marc/relators/relaterm.html) "Consultant to a project"):

```
Authors@R: c(
    person("John", "Doe", email = "jdoe@example1.com", role = c("aut", "cre")),
    person("Jane", "Smith", email = "jsmith@example2.com", role = "csp", comment = "Provided intellectual overview."))
```

...`citation('mypackagename')` will give the following:

```
To cite package ‘mypackagename’ in publications use:

  John Doe (NA). mypackagename: My package description. R package version 0.1.0.
  https://github.com/link/to/mypackagename

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {mypackagename: My package description},
    author = {John Doe},
    note = {R package version 0.1.0},
    url = {https://github.com/link/to/mypackagename},
  }
```

In addition, `?mypackagename` returns `[NA]` for the contributor under "Author(s)":

```
Maintainer: John Doe jdoe@example1.com

Other contributors:

Jane Smith jsmith@example2.com (Provided intellectual overview.) [NA]
```

Seemingly to get around this, the author of the `Hmisc` package [uses the following](https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) in his `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Author: Frank E Harrell Jr <f.harrell@vanderbilt.edu>, with
  contributions from Charles Dupont and many others.
```

How can I force R to include non-author contributors (of other roles) in the `citation()` output? Is the `Hmisc` author's approach best here? It seems like that could break the clean metadata parsing provided by `Authors@R`, so I'm hesitant to use that approach.

I would be grateful for any pointers!

Comment: When creating a citation for a journal article, you only list the authors (for nearly all citation style guides); you don't list acknowledgements. Why would that be any different than a citation for a package? The citation should just help a reader identify the source of code used. It is not meant as a comprehensive listing of all contributions. Perhaps you have a different definition of "citation."

Comment: @FrankHarrell, perhaps you can shed some light on your thinking?

Comment: Oops, he hasn't been active on this post so @ [won't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). But he is on the site, so maybe he'll see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include other roles in `citation()` output. Check [the source of `citation()`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/20e5d1d7f8df2d777fd50e9753f1256dd7c0424c/src/library/utils/R/citation.R#L1231), it parses only the author fields, there is even a note in the source code on it:

```
    ## <NOTE>
    ## Older versions took persons with no roles as "implied" authors.
    ## Now we only use persons with a name and a 'aut' role.  If there
    ## are none, we use persons with a name and a 'cre' role.
    ## If this still gives nothing (which really should not happen), we
    ## fall back to the plain text Author field.
    ## Checking will at least note the cases where there are no persons
    ## with names and 'aut' or 'cre' roles.
```

So the only way for you to include other roles is to use plain text description as in the example of Hmisc package.

Comment: Thank you for this reference! I'll accept your answer, and am grateful for your explanation.