# How can I get R to replace the text for an author's role, which is showing as '[NA]'?

Tags: r, packaging, tidyverse, r-package

This question is an offshoot of [another question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062908/how-can-i-force-r-to-include-contributors-or-other-roles-in-my-packages-citat).

I'm currently writing my first R package, following Hadley Wickham's excellent [book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) on the topic. The section of the book linked above includes examples for adding authors and contributors through the package's `DESCRIPTION` file.

Dr. Wickham notes that "The [full list of roles](http://www.loc.gov/marc/relators/relaterm.html) is extremely comprehensive. Should your package have a woodcutter ('wdc'), lyricist ('lyr') or costume designer ('cst'), rest comfortably that you can correctly describe their role in creating your package."

The problem that I'm experiencing is that `?mypackagename` returns `[NA]` for the contributor under "Author(s)" when that person's role is listed as something other than `ctb` (Contributor) -- for example, if Jane Smith below is listed as `csp` (Consultant to a Project) or, following Dr. Wickham's example above, as `wdc` (Woodcutter).

Example part of DESCRIPTION file:

```
Authors@R: c(
    person("John", "Doe", email = "jdoe@example1.com", role = c("aut", "cre")),
    person("Jane", "Smith", email = "jsmith@example2.com", role = "csp", comment = "Provided intellectual overview."))
```

Relevant output from `?mypackagename`:

```
Maintainer: John Doe jdoe@example1.com

Other contributors:

Jane Smith jsmith@example2.com (Provided intellectual overview.) [NA]
```

Is there a way to tell R what this additional role is, to replace that `[NA]` text with something more accurate?

I would be grateful for any pointers!

Comment: I just found https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.pdf, which directed me to `?person`, which states that "the new scheme also adds the possibility of specifying roles based on **a subset of** the MARC Code List for Relators (https://www.loc.gov/marc/relators/relaterm.html)" [emphasis added]. The roles it lists are author, compiler, contributor, copyright holder, creator, contractor, data contributor, thesis advisor, and translator. This doesn't answer whether R can be told about additional roles, so I'm leaving the question open. But that does seem relevant.

Comment: Further documenting my findings: The `roxygen2` [source code](https://rdrr.io/cran/roxygen2/src/R/object-package.R "R/object-package.R") contains the following dictionary:

    "aut" = "author",
    "com" = "compiler",
    "ctb" = "contributor",
    "cph" = "copyright holder",
    "cre" = "maintainer",
    "ctr" = "contractor",
    "dtc" = "data contributor",
    "fnd" = "funder",
    "ths" = "thesis advisor",
    "trl" = "translator"

Comment: Since it looks as though `roxygen` does not have a facility for adding roles, I created a [Pull Request](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/662 "roxygen Pull Request") to add all valid MARC roles.